# JAVAFX: Add some Loading Image as layer on HBox while some task processing to genrate HBoX Content

Tags: javafx

Javafx Layer put HBox

I am Developing app in javafx And I have Situation where I am updating content of HBox . So how I can notify user to wait some time while it processing . So for that I want to put loading image on Hbox like layer while it update that layer is removed.

Just Like SwingWorker in swing after done we can update scenario is there any way to do it in javafx

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do background processing on UI thread, it will result in freezing UI, so you have to use threads.

```
        Task task = new Task() {
            @Override
            protected Object call() throws Exception {
                hBox.setVisible(true);

//                Thread.sleep(5000);
//                Processing
                return null;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            hBox.setVisible(false);
        });
        new Thread(task).start();
```